# How to Count Multiple Fields and Run Calculations On Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `form_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `entry_id` (`entry_id`),
  KEY `form_id` (`form_id`),
  KEY `field_id` (`field_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=173 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And example data in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/FS5aHzae

My query:

```
SELECT count(*),
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Supporters FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` WHERE `value` = 'Supporter') AS Supporters,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Undecided FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` WHERE `value` = 'Undecided') AS Undecided,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Opposition FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` WHERE `value` = 'Opposition') AS Opposition
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(entry_id) FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields`WHERE form_id = 549)
```

With the above query, I was able to get the following results. However, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't give me a MySQL error.

`Total Enrolled` `Supporters` `Undecided` `Opposition`
            `29`          `6`         `3`          `2`

Error here:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 100' at line 5

With those results, I now want to have the `Supporters` divided by `Total Enrolled` multiplied by 100 to get the Percent of Supporters out of the 29 people enrolled. The same with the Undecided and Opposition. I am at a bit of a loss on how to do this.

Comment: your code has no limit, so the error doesn't come form the query, maybr triggers or events?

Comment: Your _Create table query_ and _Insert statement_ link require access. Why post links when you can just post the code in your question like how you did with your query? And what is the relation between your correlated subqueries?

Comment: nbk, I am not even sure.

Comment: @FanoFN, It keeps saying the code is spam so I just used google. I updated the links.

Comment: Are those `supporters`, `undecided` and `opposition` count based on `form_id=549`?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: Then that's mean your current query is incorrect. I'll post an answer to explain why it's incorrect and a query suggestion for your requirement.

Comment: @FanoFN, with regards to the percentages, is it possible to remove the decimal places?

Comment: To round it or just remove the decimal? I mean like for `20.6897`, you want it to be just `20` or round to `21`? https://dbfiddle.uk/7XuFDkDU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment above, I did asks about *"what is the relation between your correlated subqueries"* and later rephrase to *"Are those supporters, undecided and opposition count based on form_id=549?"* which you've confirmed it is. In that case, your current query is incorrect since those correlated subqueries in `SELECT` is actually selecting all rows regardless of `form_id`.

What I'm saying is, this is a standalone query:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Supporters FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` WHERE `value` = 'Supporter') 
 AS Supporters,
```

from this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(entry_id) FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields`WHERE form_id = 549
```

If you assume that the queries from your `SELECT` are getting the records from `form_id=549`, then that is incorrect.

Now, to fix that, you need to add `AND form_id = 549` in all your correlated subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT count(*),
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Supporters FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` 
         WHERE `value` = 'Supporter' AND form_id = 549) AS Supporters,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Undecided FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` 
         WHERE `value` = 'Undecided' AND form_id = 549) AS Undecided,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Opposition FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` 
         WHERE `value` = 'Opposition' AND form_id = 549) AS Opposition
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(entry_id) FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields`WHERE form_id = 549) a
```

But if you ask me, I'll suggest a single query which is a lot shorter and with only single condition for `form_id`, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entry_id) AS 'TotalEnrolled',
       SUM(`value` = 'Supporter') AS Supporters,
       SUM(`value` = 'Undecided') AS Undecided,
       SUM(`value` = 'Opposition') AS Opposition
  FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields`WHERE form_id = 549;
```

Now, from here you can do the percentage calculation like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entry_id) AS 'TotalEnrolled',
       SUM(`value` = 'Supporter') AS Supporters,
       (SUM(`value` = 'Supporter')/COUNT(DISTINCT entry_id))*100 AS 'Supporters %',
       SUM(`value` = 'Undecided') AS Undecided,
       (SUM(`value` = 'Undecided')/COUNT(DISTINCT entry_id))*100 AS 'Undecided %',
       SUM(`value` = 'Opposition') AS Opposition,
       (SUM(`value` = 'Opposition')/COUNT(DISTINCT entry_id))*100 AS 'Opposition %'
  FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields`WHERE form_id = 549;
```

Or you can make that query as a derived table and it might look *prettier* :

```
SELECT TotalEnrolled,
       Supporters,
        (Supporters/TotalEnrolled)*100 AS 'Supporters %',
       Undecided,
        (Supporters/TotalEnrolled)*100 AS '%',
       Opposition,
        (Supporters/TotalEnrolled)*100 AS 'Opposition %'
  FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entry_id) AS 'TotalEnrolled',
       SUM(`value` = 'Supporter') AS Supporters,
       SUM(`value` = 'Undecided') AS Undecided,
       SUM(`value` = 'Opposition') AS Opposition
  FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields`WHERE form_id = 549) a;
```

Results:

| TotalEnrolled | Supporters | Supporters % | Undecided | Undecided % | Opposition | Opposition % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 6 | 20.6897 | 3 | 10.3448 | 2 | 6.8966 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A9iHkRkk)